# After deleting container from Azure Container Service agent, its website still available

Tags: docker, azure-container-service

I am totally new this. I followed some article like this: (https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/container-service/container-service-docker-swarm.md)

But the strange thing is: after removing container "yeasy/simple-web", I could still open that site, even if I reboot that master linux box. How come it will happen?

Comment: your browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, and it is because browser cache. Use another browser then it is fine now.